# Using Channel Form to change the channel of an entry

Tags: safecracker

I've searched the docs and don't see any native way to change an entry from one channel to another via a channel form. (In my case the 2 channels share the same field and status groups so this should be doable. Indeed, it is possible in the CP when editing entries.)

Am I missing something, or will a plugin be required here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. The channel form outputs a hidden channel_id input

```
<input type="hidden" value="12" name="channel_id">
```

I was able to change that with javascript to the id of the new channel that I wanted to post to.